# How do I get face embedding from face obtained from ML KIT using FaceNet

Tags: android, kotlin, tensorflow, face-recognition, facenet

I'm trying to implement a face auth which analysis face of a user, stores the data and then authenticate the user with the face data stored in the memory.

I have used the googles ML Kit to detects and get the faces, how then do I carry on from here using FaceNet to get the embeddings, so I can store it and compare for authentification?

```
private fun processImageProxy(detector: FaceDetector, imageProxy: ImageProxy){

        val inputImage = InputImage.fromMediaImage(imageProxy.image!!, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)

        detector.process(inputImage)
            .addOnSuccessListener { faces ->

                Log.i("faces", faces.toString())

                binding.faceboxOverlay.clear()

                faces.forEach{ face ->
                    

                    }
                    

                }
            }

            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.e(TAG, it.message ?: it.toString())
            }

            .addOnCompleteListener {
                imageProxy.close()
            }

    }
```

Comment: Be aware that using face detection for authentication purposes could lead to serious security problems. A photo could potentially be used to authenticate for someone.

Comment: I know. Its just an assignment give to us. Can you help me?

Comment: You could use FaceLandmarks and use them to create a sort of "UID". https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/face/FaceLandmark